# How do I stop a JavaScript function once it runs

Tags: javascript, disable

The function is when the user finishing reading the article (scroll down), will pop up an alert "You finish reading!"

But how do I disable the function when the function is triggered? Otherwise the user scroll down again, the alert will pop up again...

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  let trigger = true;
  
  if (trigger && window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    trigger = false;
    alert('You finish reading!');
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: You should be using `IntersectionObserver` instead of installing a blocking event-handler on `onscroll` and checking `window`/`document` members.

Comment: Move the first `let trigger = true` ***outside*** the event handler - you're resetting the flag every time the event happens

Comment: I'd also echo @Dai's comments regarding the approach you're using here, and add that the `else` statement can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to move the `trigger` flag outside of the event handler.

Otherwise, you can improve this snippet by:

1. using [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for more efficient detection of the scroll to bottom
2. otherwise, you should throttle the event handler as it is firing a lot more than necessary now and could lead to a poor UX.
3. it would be better to `window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {})` to listen for `scroll` events, as the `onscroll` property can be overridden by anyone.

Comment: When using `window.addEventListener("scroll"` it's important to also specify `{ passive: true; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `onscroll` to `null`

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    window.onscroll = null;
    alert('You finish reading!');
  }
};
```